# Sax parsing throwing Unexpected token Exception

Tags: android, saxparseexception

I am trying to read an Xml file like this.

```
String soapResponse = readFile();
                System.out.println(soapResponse);
                //TMP END
                InputDataXMLParser inputParser = new InputDataXMLParser(soapResponse, database);    //Exception at this line
                inputParser.saveInputFiles();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();}
```

My readFile() method

```
private String readFile() throws Exception{

            AssetManager assetManager = activity.getAssets();
            InputStream ims = assetManager.open("temp/gssoOutbound.xml");

            StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while (ims.read(buffer) != -1) {
                fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
            }

            return fileContent.toString();
        }


//Stack Trace
11-05 09:58:15.766: W/System.err(21020): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT 
11-05 09:58:15.766: W/System.err(21020): URRICANE DISH D...@2:237 in java.io.StringReader@2bed3b20) 
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at org.col.gsso.sap.parser.InputDataXMLParser.getDomElement(InputDataXMLParser.java:510)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at org.col.gsso.sap.parser.InputDataXMLParser.saveInputFiles(InputDataXMLParser.java:106)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at com.gps.colpal.ToPalmDownloadAsycTask.doInBackground(ToPalmDownloadAsycTask.java:102)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at com.gps.colpal.ToPalmDownloadAsycTask.doInBackground(ToPalmDownloadAsycTask.java:1)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-05 09:58:15.786: W/System.err(21020):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-05 09:58:15.886: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21020): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

But it's throwing Unexcepted exception, any one any idea about it.

Comment: The stack trace and a pointer to what line causes it would be much helpful..

Comment: Updated with stack trace and exact location of exception.